# When updating stock via soap API some random products stock not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, soap-api-v2

### Background

We have a live site. When we try to update stock levels via Soap API some products will not update but we have no errors. I have taken one of the products that would not update and made a copy, this updated first time!

I have put the code below but cannot see any issues with it. I have looked at the product information for the items that update vs those that will not and there is nothing different.

Any ideas where else to look? Any help would be very much appreciated!

### This works:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">SESSIONIDGOESHERE</sessionId>
         <product xsi:type="xsd:string">12</product>
         <data xsi:type="urn:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity">
            <qty xsi:type="xsd:string">15</qty>
         </data>
      </urn:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateResponse>
         <result xsi:type="xsd:int">1</result>
      </ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

### This doesn't:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">SESSIONIDGOESHERE</sessionId>
         <product xsi:type="xsd:string">11</product>
         <data xsi:type="urn:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity">
            <qty xsi:type="xsd:string">15</qty>
         </data>
      </urn:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateResponse>
         <result xsi:type="xsd:int">1</result>
      </ns1:catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: I have added example code now

Comment: The code I have added is identical other than the product No., but that is the point! The problem is not with this code, I have recreated one of the products that was not updating using identical information and it works. This being the case what other variable could cause this?